# Python & SCons & Matlab: Wrong command input

Tags: python, matlab, scons, tex, mex

I am using SCons to install a package, but when I try to compile with mex, the matlab compiler, it runs other command from pdfTeX with same name. To solve this problem on bash, I've just changed .bashrc:

alias mex="/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/bin/mex"

but I dont know how to change it on SCons environment. Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Managed to find the solution, but since my account is new, I cant post it, tomorrow I will add the solution...

Comment: I would suggest to set MEX_PATH env. to your matlab bin path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix this problem. On SCons, the environment it sees is from the instance:

```
env = Environment(..., ENV = os.environ)
```

What I did was to add to os.environ the path of the matlab mex, by doing:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = matlabPath + '/bin:' +  os.environ['PATH'];
```

Where matlabPath is the Matlab Path, e.g.:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app
```

That's it!

Comment: Why can't you add the MATLAB bin path directly to ENV['PATH']?

Comment: Are you saying something like: env = Environment(..., ENV = (matlabPath + '/bin:' +  os.environ['PATH']))? I havent just thought of doing that, but I think it's better. Thank you x)